# _.each makes duplicates when loop through nested object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I trying to make loop through nested object using underscore.

my object looks like this:

```
var someObject = [{
    "name": "Chair",
    "title": "Chairs",
    "items": [{
           "name": "Recliner",
           "title": "Recliner Chair",
           "type": "Chair",
           "quantity": "1"
        }, 
        {
           "name": "Club/Armchair",
           "title": "Club/Armchair",
           "type": "Chair",
           "quantity": 1
        }]
}]
```

but when a return object it store on child object and makes two diplicate

```
<%_.each(someObject, function(a){%>

    <%_.each(a, function(b){%>

        <<%_.each(b.items, function(c){%>


                 <li><%= c.name + " " + c.title></li>


        <%});%>
    <%});%>
<%});%>
```

please help!

Comment: `var someList = ...` would seem to be a better name

Answer (score 1):

It looks you have an extra loop in there. try removing the loop

`<%_.each(a, function(b){%>`

and see if that fixes it

Comment: i get child objects, without this loop i cant get attributes

Comment: @BobDylan: But you're accessing `a.items` anyway?

Comment: The first loop should return the high level object which contains name, title and items. At that point you should loop through a.items

Comment: i use a.items to access